# MongoDB 2.4 new Text Index feature

Tags: mongodb

So I have a weirdly configured DB imported into MongoDB, looks like this:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("51191d45890311d9b2a0865d"),
"field1" : "randomtextstuff",
"field2" : "randomtextstuff",
"field3" : "randomtextstuff",
"field4" : "randomtextstuff",
"field5" : "randomtextstuff"
```

Some documents have 100 fields others have non.

So I wanted to test the new text search, so I attempted the following index:

```
db.profile_specialties.ensureIndex({"field1":"text",
"field2":"text",
"field3":"text",
"field4":"text",
"field5":"text",
"field6":"text",
... All the way to 100
"field96":"text",
"field97":"text",
"field98":"text",
"field99":"text",
"field100":"text"})
```

The returned error message was:

```
{
        "err" : "ns name too long, max size is 128",
        "code" : 10080,
        "n" : 0,
        "connectionId" : 1,
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Has any one else experiences this problem?

Comment: Straight from the docs: `Index names, including their full namespace (i.e. database.collection) can be no longer than 128 characters. See the db.collection.getIndexes() field name for the names of existing indexes.` You can only have 1 text index per collection as well.

Answer (score 2):

With MongoDB 2.4 text search you can use the new [wildcard specifier (`$**`)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/text-indexes/#index-all-fields) to index all fields with string content:

```
db.profile_specialties.ensureIndex("$**":"text"})
```

You should consider that a text index across all fields is going to be very large, though.

Comment: I'm not sure how that works because the documentation is not clear. I quote "A collection can have at most one text index." from here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/text-search/#create-a-text-index

Comment: You can have at most one text index, but that index can be across one or more fields.  The `$**` specifier will index all fields with string content.